# How to retrieve File from Parse to display on PFQueryTableVIewController?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm trying to retrieve users profile pictures(File) from Parse onto my `PFQueryTableViewController`. I believe I've written my code correctly but I'm probably doing something wrong. So how do I retrieve users images from parse to display on my query?

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell? {
   let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TCell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! Tweets


if let userTweet : PFObject = self.tweets.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as! PFObject {

cell.username.text = object["account"] as? String
cell.post.text = object["post"] as? String
cell.post.numberOfLines = 0

    if let Pic = object["photo"] as? PFFile {
        cell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "Image")
        cell.userImage.file = Pic
    }

    }
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Did you debug and check `userImage` exists?

Comment: I get an error at 'cell.userImage.file= pic' saying value of UIImageView has no member 'file'

Comment: UIImageView doesn't implement `file`.  You may be expecting that your cell's image view is a `PFImageView`, which hides the work of fetching the contents of the file, interpreting those contents as an image, and setting its imageView (probably its superclass's) image to the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not loading the `PFFile` for one.

```
if let pic = object["photo"] as? PFFile {
    // Make sure your imageView is a PFImageView
    let imageView = cell.userImage as! PFImageView
    // I assume this is the placeholder image while your load your image files from Parse
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image.png")
    imageView.file = pic
    // Load the image file however you see fit
    imageView.loadInBackground(nil) 
}
```

As a side note, It's good practice to not capitalize your constants due to the chance they could get confused with class names in your code.

Comment: Okay so I don't run in to errors now when I use that code, however, in Parse I don't see the images of the users in my Class when I post something. Is that a separate issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is using a `PFImageView`, but that the cell subclass is presenting it as a `UIImageView` so the compiler is complaining. You need to make sure that the image view is properly set and exposed as a `PFImageView`.